# php（DBから取得したの中身の表示）をJsonで変換しjavascriptで画面上に表示させたい。

Tags: javascript, php, monaca, json

Monaca側でconsole.log("投稿完了")まではできているのですが，
この後処理，JSONで変換されたphpの文（DBの中身を表示させたもの）JavascriptでMonaca上の画面に表示させる部分がよくわからなかったのでアドバイスの方をお願いします。

---

Monaca側

```
                //口コミのボタンを押すとページ遷移と更新を同時に行う 
                  function anime1() {
                  app.slidingMenu.setMainPage('page1.html', {closeMenu:true});
                  }

                  function anime2() {
                  console.log("jh");
                  // Ajaxで～.phpを利用してDBにアクセス
                     $.ajax({
                     type: "POST",
                     scriptCharset: 'utf-8',
                     dataType: "jsonp",
                     url: サーバーにある～.phpファイル名

                     }).done(function(data){
                  console.log("投稿完了！");


                   //for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)

                   //document.write $(':text[name="senderName"]')
                   //.append($('<option>').html(data[i]  ["japanese"]).val(data[i]["id"]));
         // }

                   }).fail(function(data){
                   alert('error!!!');
                   console.log("error");
                   });
            }


            </script>
```

php側

```
          <?php

          require_once('config.php');

          $result=$pdo->prepare("select*from 13DB066_test");
          $result->execute();
          $result_value=$result->fetchAll();

          header('Content-type: application/json');

          echo json_encode( $result_value );


          // echo $result_value[$i]["text1"] ;
          // echo $result_value[$i]["text2"] ;
          // echo $result_value[$i]["text3"] ;
          // echo $result_value[$i]["text4"] ;

          // }
          ?>
```

Comment: html があるサイトと php が動いているサーバは別のオリジンですか？

Comment: HTMLはMonacaというハイブリッドアプリ開発プラットフォームでphpは外部サーバーにおいていて，phpはDBの中身を引っ張ってきています。

Answer (score 1):

外部サーバでかつ CORS ではないのならば、JSONP (Pが要ります) になります。

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    scriptCharset: 'utf-8',
    dataType: "jsonp",
    url: 'http://example.com/foo.php?callback=?'
}).done(function(data){
```

こうしておき php 側は

```
<?php
require_once('config.php');

$result = $pdo->prepare("select*from 13DB066_test");
$result->execute();
$result_value=$result->fetchAll();

header('Content-type: application/json');

$callback = $_GET['callback'];
if ($callback) {
  // 関数名チェックが必要
  echo $callback + '(' + json_encode( $result_value ) + ')';
} else {
  echo json_encode( $result_value );
}

// echo $result_value[$i]["text1"] ;
// echo $result_value[$i]["text2"] ;
// echo $result_value[$i]["text3"] ;
// echo $result_value[$i]["text4"] ;

// }
?>
```

この様に callback で返せる様にします。jQuery の `callback=?` の `?` にはユニークな関数名が入るので php ではそのまま関数呼び出しとして返す必要があります。
もちろん javascript の関数として許せる名称かどうかチェックすべきです。